# Raspberry (HDMI) to monitor(VGA) Does a cable work?

Tags: hdmi, setup, monitoring, cable

Now I have seen some HDMI to VGA Cables, but on some forums people say it won't work. I have a monitor with just VGA input and I want to connect my Raspberry Pi to it.

Will a HDMI to VGA cable work? If not, what would be the cheapest solution for my problem?

Comment: Some older monitors also have a DVI input. HDMI-to-DVI cables exist. HDMI-to-VGA doesn't exist!!! HDMI is digital, while VGA is analog. HDMI-to-VGA adapters are quit expensive. Almost the price of a cheap hdmi monitor. If money is an option, just go to a 2nd-handsstore and get a monitor with a DVI input.

Comment: @Gerben Will HDMI to Laptop HDMI work?

Comment: No. Both are outputs. Though it could generate magical blue smoke :-)

Comment: Mine doen't work. I bought HDMI-to-VGA cable and screen displayed "Cable Not Connected".

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12590/does-hdmi-to-vga-cable-works-with-raspberry-pi

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/118141/second-acer-monitor-x183h-native-1366-x-768-hdmi-to-vga-adapters-input-not-supp see #Connection Type at top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an analog signal for VGA, which I do not believe is present in the HDMI version of DVI, so a plain cable will never work.

Converters are expensive. The cheapest solution will be another, used monitor or HDMI capable tv.

Answer (score 2):

I have used multiple times a HDMI to VGA adaptor, like [this one.](https://www.google.nl/search?q=hdmi%20to%20vga%20adapter&safe=off&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=950&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=WQr2VJaoNcut7Aag4ID4BQ&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#imgdii=_&imgrc=newKKtfKow_iAM%253A%3BAfGqKAp8iC0oiM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Ftitan-ice.co.za%252Fimages%252Fdetailed%252F13%252FCO-HDMIDSUB.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Ftitan-ice.co.za%252Fhdmi-to-vga-d-sub-display-adapter-converter.html%3B500%3B387)

The work very well, also  apple HDMI to VGA adaptors work, like [this one](http://store.apple.com/us/product/H9139VC/B/kanex-atv-pro-hdmi-to-vga-adapter-with-audio-support)

The apple one is expensive, but the first one isn't, here in the Netherlands approximately 10-15 euro's.($15).

A HDMI to VGA cable doesn't work, the signal should be converted to analog, that's wy you need an adaptor.

Answer (score 1):

[Gert VGA 666](https://www.pi-supply.com/product/gert-vga-666-hardware-vga-raspberry-pi/) is another option, but you need to solder it together yourself and it only works on Pis with a 40-pin GPIO connector (Model B+, Model A+, Raspberry Pi 2).

Answer (score 0):

I have had routine success over a number of years with the [Tripp Lite HDMI to VGA Converter Adapter (P131-06N)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EZ3SY1A) which was $21 the last I checked. To use if you will need to modify the config.txt file BEFORE you try using the monitor. Nothing shows up until you make these changes.

Uncomment the following lines and set to the values listed:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug = 1
hdmi_group = 2
hdmi_mode = 16
```

([you may want to change this](http://elinux.org/RPiconfig#Video_mode_options) if the aspect ratio looks a little off but it is a good starting place. Click the link and scroll to the DMT options)

```
hdmi_drive = 2
```

All other graphics options in config.txt should be commented out.