# Do HDMI to VGA cables work with Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian, hdmi

Do these kinds of HDMI to VGA cables work with Raspberry Pi?

[image: HDMI to VGA adapter]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9881/raspberry-hdmi-to-monitorvga-does-a-cable-work

Comment: It is highly likely this cable will NOT work. Try and search for Active HDMI to VGA. That is what I use and works fine. Some even have Audio out. This cable works with devices that understand VGA over HDMI. Not many.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're lucky and with some struggle it will work.  Maybe you're unlucky and it won't work at all.  With all due respect to Willem van Doesburg, it may look like the exact same cable but it might not be.  Plus your system may be different to his, so YMMV.

- Another related question: [Can a simple cable convert HDMI output to VGA?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/222/can-a-simple-cable-convert-hdmi-output-to-vga?rq=1)
- Wiki page: [Hardware Basic Setup at eLinux.org](http://elinux.org/RPi_Hardware_Basic_Setup#Display)
- Forum thread: [HDMI to VGA converter, no video](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=269212)

In summary, you have to hope that (1) this particular cable includes a (passive) digital-to-analog converter, and that (2) your Pi and your Pi's power supply are able to cope with powering this converter.  Then you may need to alter your Pi's config to set the resolution to something that your monitor can cope with.  Read the links.

Answer (score 1):

For me that cable didn't work. I read a lot articles about that after I buy it and in most (or all) of them saying that passive HDMI to VGA convertor wont work for RPI. Dont buy it. If you havn't already.

Answer (score 0):

yes this will work, I use the exact same cable.

Comment: What changes did you made in config.txt @Willem van Doesburg

Comment: none, HDMI is turned on by default if you use Raspbian.

Comment: In wiki it says HDMI to VGA cable wont work only converters work

Comment: I can't speak for the wiki. This is just my experience. It was plug and play for me.

Comment: Possibly your TV understands VGA over HDMI. BUt usually this cable only works on BluRay players.