# Second Acer monitor X183H native 1366 x 768 HDMI-to-VGA adapters "Input Not Supported" (*First AcerG195W works great)

Tags: hdmi, screen, config.txt, output, raspberry-pi-os

#Raspberry Pi w/ latest Raspbian (Raspberry's OS) (which I have connected as a desktop computer)
https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b/specifications/?resellerType=home 
#Connection type
https://www.amazon.ca/UNSOEN-Adapter-Converter-Portable-Connector/dp/B07XGQBCH5 
#Monitor 1
https://www.cnet.com/products/acer-g195w-abd-lcd-monitor-19/ 
#Monitor 2
https://www.cnet.com/products/acer-x183hb-lcd-monitor-18-5/

The problem:

I am aware that something doesn't seem to like the Native Resolution: 1366 x 768 at 75 Hz for the X183H (Monitor 2). I have not been able to correct the issue of the "Input Not Supported" bouncing around Monitor 2. I can look past this annoying little box and view my second monitor no problem, but was wondering if there might be a way to easily disable this (prob not). Since I do enjoy the current configuration, HDMI-1 1440x900 @59.9hz / HDMI-2 1920x1080 @60hz
(and all other currently available options for HDMI-2 cause my screen to look absolutely horrendous because of the 1366x768 issue), further along I have disabled `Overscan` for the output, so for HDMI-2 the monitor accepts and displays at the above settings but is under the impression it does not.

Attempted Fixes:

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

Locate and edit:

```
#uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
hdmi_group=2<br>
hdmi_mode=87<br>
hdmi_cvt=1360 768 60
```

Ctrl+x ..Save ..`/boot/config.txt` ..enter

Reboot:
but this applies the settings to HDMI-1 when I only want for HDMI-2 (and HDMI-2 remains "broke")

Enabled settings in `config.txt`.

```
Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on
[pi4]
#Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2
[all]
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
#NOOBS Auto-generated Settings:
start_x=1
gpu_mem=128
```

Thank you for any insight you might have in reference to my issue.

Comment: If you have lost your login credentials see *["I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)*.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED : Adding these some lines to /boot/config.txt
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/conditional.md

Look for: The

```
[HDMI:*]
```

filter which works for Pi 4 only.

Use group=1 (CEA) for televisions or group=2 (DMT) for monitors.

Select mode from list (using the output from a `tvservice -v -m DMT` command)

```
#mode 47: 1440x900 @ 60Hz 16:10, clock:106MHz progressive
hdmi_group:0=2
hdmi_mode:0=47 

#mode 85: 1280x720 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz progressive
hdmi_group:1=2
hdmi_mode:1=85
```

functional although not ideal.

Avoid using 1366x768 as that may not work with your TV or monitor.

Comment: If you have lost your login credentials see *["I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)*.

Comment: solution holds true with new release :)